# Failed prop type: Material-UI: Either children, image, src or component prop must be specified. at CardMedia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use CardMedia component from Material-ui and and was getting this error '**Failed prop type: Material-UI: Either `children`, `image`, `src` or `component` prop must be specified.
at CardMedia**' tried many solution like adding component='img' it removed the error but the image wasn't displayed (removes the error but breaks it).
**it works fine with out it tho but i want to know why i kept getting the error**

"@material-ui/core": "4.12.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"react": "^17.0.2",

```html
<CardMedia
  className={media}
  image={post.selectedFile}
  title={post.title}
  // component="image"
  // component="img"
/>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or warning be specific?

Answer (score 0):

After some Debugging found out that the CardMedia component is a Div and my styles were implied on a div and specifying it as an image component using the line component="img", it broke my css, and the image was just 'Hiding lol' it was there all along.